# Apache: restrict access to folder based on certificate

Tags: apache-2.4, certificate

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

I have created a simple Apache srv on 2.4.25

The srv has a cert from letsencrypt and enforces access to https only.
I have a "secret" folder (test). It has been protected by basic auth (user/PW).
This means that if you access https://www.example.org/test, you'll be prompted for authentication; works fine.

Now the question:
I would like to enforce that access to this folder is only allowed from clients (in this case some phones). The phones has a device certificate, and I would like to use this cert for authentication. However the cert is not from a trusted CA like letsencrypt or Digicert. They are signed by the company that manufactors the phone (self-signed)

My thought is to import the CA, and then look up if the request to access the folder is from a phone(allowed) or not. I tried to add :

SSLVerifyClient require

SSLVerifyDepth 1

SSLCACertificatePath /path/to/ssl/

to the folder, but this causes the srv to start as:
"Your SSL library does not have support for per-directory CA"

Seems that this takes bit more to get working, so any hints and advises will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418849/per-directory-ca-in-httpd-2-4-mod-ssl

Comment: Here is a possible workaround: https://superuser.com/questions/1055171/apache-and-support-for-per-directory-ca

Comment: Hello René and thanks for posting your question! It would help if you could include your httpd configuration.  As @GeraldSchneider mentioned, it seems your question has already been answered.